Arguments inside a C function
I am recently studying functions in C and I often notice (from online examples) that function in the main.c contains arguments with a different name than what they are called in the file in which it is declared.
Assume that PIDController is a struct, but let's focus on the other two parameters (Iq_ref and Iq):
What I usually see:
In main.c:
Vq = PID(&PID_Iq, Iq_ref, Iq);

In the generic function PID.c:
float PID(PIDController *pid, float ref, float measure) {..}

What I take for granted is, instead, to give them the same name:
In main.c:
Vq = PID(&PID_Iq, Iq_ref, Iq);

In the generic function PID.c:
float PID(PIDController *pid, float Iq_ref, float Iq) {..}

Is this wrong?
Maybe I have a double variable declaration in two different files?

Consider a generic float sum(float a, float b); - you might want to call it with sum(total_item_price, sales_tax).

You code calling the function should have descriptive names, like sqrt(determinant), but the function itself does well with a generic identifier, like double sqrt(double x);. This way it's easy to calculate the square root of the "determinant", of the "velocity", of the "weight", ... with one single function

They are different variables independent of the names. In the function definition, you have the names for the variables that are used in the function and are given values from outside at the function call. In the function call you have the values that are used to provide the initial values of those variables for that call. Those values could be expressions or just variables. If variables, they might or might not happen to have the same name as the formal parameters they are used to initialized. (C is call by value, non call by value languages would need different phrasing for accuracy.)

@AKX @pmg yes, I might want to call it what you say, but I might also want to call it float sum(float a, float b); in the main.c and, same, float sum(float a, float b); under the main function (or in another .c file) .. this would not be wrong, right? Because it is very confusing to me to call the "variables" of the function by different names
